# How do I get "this" into this function... jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got something like the following:

```
MyShape = function() {

    var _container = {
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }


    this.draw() { 
       //do stuff...
    }

    $('#slider-1').bind('change', function(event, ui) {

        _container.width = $('#slider-1').val();
        this.draw();

    });


};
```

I'm using the jquery slider to dynamically change the width of my shape, then I call .draw() to redraw the shape. I keep getting this error though:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'draw'

I'm fairly sure it's because I need to pass the context "this" into the change function, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 8):

This is caused because [JavaScript's `this` is dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197822/how-does-this-work-in-javascript).

You can use `Function.prototype.bind` like so:

```
$('#slider-1').on('change', function(event, ui) {

    _container.width = $('slider-1').val();
    this.draw();

}.bind(this) /* use the same this value */);
```

Or you can use a closure variable

```
var that = this;
$('#slider-1').on('change', function(event, ui) {

    _container.width = $('slider-1').val();
    that.draw();

});
```

Comment: Also [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), though, `bind` is cleaner in this example, I think.

Comment: @Benjamin - nice timely edit; I was going to point out that you needed to use `.on` :)

Comment: @Tyblitz: `.on()` may be preferred, but it's not needed.

Comment: @user602525: Be aware that the `Function.prototype.bind()` used in the first example isn't available in IE8 and lower, as well as some other older browsers.

Comment: `.bind` just aliases `on`. This is its full source code `function(types, data, fn) { return this.on(types, null, data, fn);}` . It's better to use `.on` since it's the newer interface.