# Explanation, "this" syntax JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

So I was making a node app that had a conditional statement in the class constructor, if this then variable is equal to that, else variable equal to that. However, when I initialize that variable I want to change depending on the boolean statement with "this" syntax it gives me an error in the console. Why does this happen? And how can I initialize that variable if I can't initialize it more than once with "this" syntax in JS?

Update:

I was given [How does 'this' work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197822/how-does-this-work-in-javascript) to see if this helps, and it has nothing to do with what I asked. To be more specific, it's like why can I do this `var test; if(true){var test = 1}else{var test = 0}` and not this `if(true){this.test = 1}else{this.test = 0}` and be able to use the variable all throughout my app.

code:

```
class Wallet {
  constructor(secret) {
      //ADDED SECRET PARAMETER
    this.secret = secret;
    
    this.balance = STARTING_BALANCE;

    if(this.secret === null || undefined)
    {
        this.keyPair = ec.genKeyPair();
    
        this.publicKey = this.keyPair.getPublic().encode('hex');
    }
    else
    {
        this.keyPair = ec.keyFromPrivate(this.secret);
        
        this.storeKeys = this.keyPair.toString('hex');
        
        //fs.writeFileSync('../secret.json');
        this.publicKey = this.keyPair.getPublic().encode('hex');
    }

    
  }
```

console error:

```
/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:622
    var w = this.words[this.length - 1];
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of null
    at BN.bitLength (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:622:23)
    at Point._hasDoubles (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curve/base.js:332:48)
    at Point.mul (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/curve/short.js:426:17)
    at KeyPair.getPublic (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/elliptic/lib/elliptic/ec/key.js:61:26)
    at new Wallet (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/wallet/index.js:26:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/blockchain/dataBlock.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does 'this' work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197822/how-does-this-work-in-javascript)

Comment: so for future references and less confusion, what I wrote works as it is intended and it's not a misusing of this in JS, right epascarello?

Comment: research JS variable SCOPE, you need to understand scoping before the `this` var in JS makes sense and why and how its used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is your conditional:

```
this.secret === null || undefined
```

should be

```
this.secret === null || this.secret === undefined
```

if you want to be explicit but you could just use a double equals instead of triple for a truthy answer that would include null or undefined:

```
this.secret == null
```

The second problem, which makes it difficult to answer your question, is it's totally unclear what `this.words` is, what you're trying to get the `length` of, and why.

If you're trying to truncate the last letter of the variable `this.words`, for example, you would do:

```
const w = this.words.splice(0, this.words.length - 1)
```

Only strings and arrays have a `length`, unless you've added a length to your own class's prototype. So `this.length` wouldn't work unless `this` is a string or an array or a class with a custom length method.

Comment: Thank you for useful information, I will get back to this after experimenting on some things.

Comment: it all derived from my silly conditional mistake. Thank you for answering this question, I have no eyes.

Comment: I feel like StackOverflow would eliminate a lot of downvotes by setting up a new site that's explicitly just for getting a second set of eyes on your code to spot dumb self-inflicted bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I am Assuming that your are calling your class in some other file using a import statement and passing it a random string inside a `" "`.

If that is the case then you need to handle that input inside your `class Wallet`  and sanitize it for the expected input..

somehow somewhere the given input is having a break code such as `\n` which is the cause of this error.. maybe a use of `typeof()` to check that you have a valid string before this line of code

```
this.keyPair = ec.keyFromPrivate(this.secret);
```

can prevent the error..

and yes the problem in previous answer are there too..