# Why doesn't JavaScript function aliasing work?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, firebug, alias

I have some Firebug console function calls that I wanted to disable when Firebug wasn't enabled, e.g. console isn't defined. This works fine in IE6 and FF3, but not in Chrome:

```
var log;

if(console){
  log = console.log;
}else{
  log = function(){ return; }
}
```

I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal Invocation" in Chrome =/

I read about the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work), where you have to apply a context, which is kind of new to me... and I can't seem to figure how to accomplish the above in all browsers...

Comment: I should note that this question has enhanced my understanding of javascript!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you should persist the context :

```
var log;

if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function"){
  // use apply to preserve context and invocations with multiple arguments
  log = function () { console.log.apply(console, arguments); };
} else {
  log = function(){ return; }
}
```

What is happening is that the context (the `this` value), is implicitly set when you call a function, for example:

```
var obj = {
  method: function () { return this; }
};

obj.method() === obj; // true
```

In this case, you are calling a function that is defined as a property of an object, when the function is invoked, the `this` value is set to that object.

Now as in your example, if you copy a reference of that method to a variable:

```
var method = obj.method;
method() === window; // global object
```

As you can see, the `this` value refers to the global object.

So, to avoid this implicit behavior you can set the context explicitly, with the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) functions.

Comment: `if (console)` will cause a "console is not defined" error, if it's not defined for the browser or if it's disabled. You're better of checking `(window.console)` or even `(typeof console != "undefined)"`.

Comment: @Ates, yes, a `ReferenceError` will be produced if `console` is not defined, `if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function")` its safer, edited.

Comment: yeah I do check for typeof, i was just simplifying since that really isnt the issue

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that console is not just defined by FireBug, but also exists in IE8 & Chrome.

Comment: Funny story, I totally understand all this fun stuff now

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that, in this answer, `apply()` is being called within a closure, making it unnecessary since the closure will capture `console` to its own execution context. In this answer, calling `console.log( arguments );` within the anonymous function is sufficient. I think a clearer alternative is to omit the closure and use `bind()` instead of `apply()`: `log = console.bind( console );`

Answer (score 7):

The problem with wrapping a function (like console.log) in a function is that it loses its context, i.e. it will not show the correct line number of the file that we've put our "log" shortcut in.

Instead I suggest something like this:

```
 window.log = ((window.console && window.console.log) ?
              console.log.bind(console) : 
              function(){});
```

This works with firebug & chrome dev tools and does not throw errors when no console is available. And - most importantly - shows the correct file & line number.

Comment: Great! The only answer the keeps line number.

Comment: I have been searching for HOURS trying to find an way to do this and keep the filename and line number of the console. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work:

```
log("hi");
```

While this does:

```
log.call(console, "hi");
```

It is obvious that you need to call the aliased function with the correct context -- as you yourself have mentioned.

I think you'll have to use a function wrapper (a closure that has a reference to the original context) rather than an alias...

#### Update

Also note that if you check for `console` directly, you may get a run-time error when the variable doesn't exist. You're better off checking it explicitly as `window.console`. Here's one way to implement a conditional `log` wrapper:

```
var log = (function (console) {
    return console
        ? function () { console.log.apply(console, arguments); }
        : function () {}
})(window.console);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution modifies the earlier and excellent answer from [CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) to work with IE8. You’ll need to open the IE8 console (press F12) before executing this. (If you forget, you’ll need to exit IE8 entirely and start again because even if the console exists, IE8 won’t subsequently create the **console** object.)

Note that we don’t set the context, which was the original problem but, as it turns out, IE8 doesn’t require that context. (Good thing, because IE8 also doesn’t provide the **apply** method on the **console.log** object!).

This code works with the latest versions of Chrome, FireFox, and MSIE. (It is compatible with MSIE6 and doesn’t throw an error.)

```
if((typeof console !== "undefined") && ((typeof console.log) !== "undefined"))
{
  if ((typeof console.log.apply !== "undefined"))
  {
    log = function() { console.log.apply(console,arguments) };
  }
  else
  {
    log = console.log;
  }
}
else
{
  log = function() {};
  // alert("No debug console");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
var log;

log = function() {
  if ((window.console != null) && (window.console.log.apply != null)) {
    return console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  } else {
    return function() {};
  }
};
```