# Assigning document.getElementById to another function

Tags: javascript, first-class-functions

I am trying to do the following in JavaScript:

```
var gete = document.getElementById;
```

But I am getting the following error (From FireBug's Console):

`uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object" nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8080/im_ass1/ :: anonymous :: line 15" data: no`]

Now obviously I can wrap the function as follows:

```
var gete = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

But what is the reason I'm getting the above exception when assigning the function to another name?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Firefox and Firebug? I don't get any errors doing this.

Comment: My current version is: `3.6.3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To invoke an alias of `document.getElementById` in Firefox and Google Chrome, you should be doing it as follows:

```
var gete = document.getElementById;
gete.call(document, 'header').innerHTML = 'new';
```

You may want to check out the following Stack Overflow post for a detailed explanation behind this:

- [JavaScript function aliasing doesn’t seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: @Andreas: It's a pleasure to meet a compatriot! :)

Answer (score 7):

ECMAScript 5 introduces the `bind()` function that binds a function with an object so that it can be called directly without having to use `func.call(thisObj)` for each call.

```
var func = document.getElementById.bind(document);
func("foo");  // We don't have to use func.call(doument, "foo")
```

`bind()` was first available in the [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) library and was later added to the language.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind or call or apply if you like, or you can assign the function directly,
as you observed-

```
var gete= function(s){return document.getElementById(s)}
```

But why not improve it a tad, or what's the use?

```
var gete= function(s){return s && s.nodeType==1? s: document.getElementById(s)}
```