# Using variables for document.getElementById and document.createElement

Tags: javascript, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t I have a direct reference to document.createElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910171/why-cant-i-have-a-direct-reference-to-document-createelement)

I am quite new to Js and have been playing around with it.
Since `document.getElementById` & `doucment.createElement` is quite long I have decided to put it in a variable;
eg `var d = document.createElement;`

1. However when I call it like `var someElement = d("p");` I get "TypeError: Illegal invocation" and I'm not sure what that means.
2. If I separate the `document` object, `var d = document;` and then give that a property like so: `d.e = d.createElement;` then use it to create an element `someElement = d.e("p")` it works.

Can someone explain what causes 1. to fail and why 2. works?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap them in a function so that you can call them from the `document` object.

```
var d = function(name) {
    return document.createElement(name);
};
```

This is simply a requirement of the `createElement` method implementation. It needs to know what `document` it should be creating the element from.

When you detach a method from an object, the method has no memory of the original object.

That's why this works:

```
d.e("p");
```

Since `e` is a reference to the `createElement` method, and it is being called from `d`, which is a reference to the `document`, you're effectively doing the same as:

```
document.createElement("p");
```

Comment: Ok i understand that. I expected core js objects to be special so that thought would have never come to mind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you use this notation in JavaScript:

```
objectName.methodName(arguments)
```

the method is informed (via the special value `this`) of the object that you're calling it on. So, when you copy a method from one object to another, it actually becomes a method of the new object.

If you treat a method as just a normal function and copy it to a local variable, and then call it normally:

```
localVariableNameHoldingMethod(arguments)
```

then its `this` will be the global object (`window`).