# Is it safe to copy a reference to a native JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, reference, native

For example

```
var w = document.getElementById;
var b = w('header');
var c = w('footer');
var d = w('body');
```

**Edit:** Semicolons are another one of those big arguments. I thought I would edit the question for fun.

**Edit:** Responses to [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151200/andrey)'s comments found on his answer.

*"How does copying reference make it more effective with JS compilers?"*
**Response:** JS compilers are to shorten and/or obfuscate code. If there were 40 calls to `document.getElementById(..)`, it would be much more compact if they called `getById(..)` which would be renamed to something like `O(..)`.

*"Also, when you handle html element events, you usually specify a js method, and inside the method you put the logic, not directly in the html event handlers - that is not required but a good practice"*
**Response:** I know. But we have many many web systems and they rarely follow good practice completely.

*"Also, using built in methods directly makes the code way more readable"*
**Response:** Given these two examples, I think the latter is more readable

```
document.getElementById('total').value = document.getElementById('subtotal').value + document.getElementById('salestax').value - document.getElementById('discount').value
document.getElementById('yousaved').value = document.getElementById('discount').value / (document.getElementById('subtotal').value + document.getElementById('salestax').value)
```

or

```
var byId = document.getElementById
byId('total').value = byId('subtotal').value + byId('salestax').value - byId('discount').value
byId('yousaved').value = byId('discount').value / (byId('subtotal').value + byId('salestax').value)
```

Comment: Your semicolons seem to have gone missing

Comment: There are a lot of people out here who get mad at me for that, but I have my personal preferences. @Matti

Comment: @George: How about switching to VBScript then, you can't even *have* semicolons in VBScript!

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Semicolons? They are not required in JS. Or was it some hidden sarcasm? :)

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: Sometimes I have hard time recognizing when people are messing with me :)

Comment: @Andrey: They are required in the same sense that using sensible function and variable names are required.

Comment: @Matti: you are commenting on coding style which is completely irrelevant, especially since George already expressed his preferences in this area. His code is 100% valid, the end.

Comment: @Martin: So if my coding preference was to name all my functions using UUID identifiers, you would be 100% OK with that?

Comment: @George: there is nothing wrong with the reference, go ahead, use it to your hearts desire. Just remember that if others need to maintain your code later, they might just hate you for it ;)

Comment: @Matti: sure, whatever floats your boat, it's your code.

Comment: @Matti: I think you should moderate your tone a little... the idea with this forum is to help others, and i doubt your comments here are helpful to anyone.

Comment: @Martin: I sincerely hope that they will be helpful to someone else who is considering writing bad code.

Comment: I don't doubt that you do, however I am sure they won't, and that will be the last of this nonsense for me, have a fantastic time ranting on, you seem to be pretty good at it ;)

Comment: @Matti: using semicolons in JS is not considered "good practice", it's just a matter of habit - usually developers who use JS also use some server side language where semicolons ARE required. If you know otherwise, please show a link where this good practice described.

Comment: @Andrey: Here, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: @Matti: Sorry, but I don't participate in holly wars. There are couple of cases when you DO NEED semicolons; the rest (like OP's example) is pure preference and arguing about it is pointless.

Comment: @Andrey: You ask for a link, I give you one and you're accusing me of taking part in a holy war of some sort? There is no war here, no, there are only facts.

Comment: That link explained why you need semicolons in one particular case which I agree with. I was asking for a link with common good practices of using JS, where it states that a common rule is to end all statements with semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean

```
var w = document.getElementById
```

?

Thsi link explains in detail why you shouldn't do that: [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean. I am just a little nervous about making a copy of a (reference to a) native method because I have never done it before and, you know, "Windows Internet Explorer". So I thought I would post a question up here to get a few experienced eyes over it before I start doing it.

Comment: What's the matter with 'Windows Internet Explorer'?

Comment: And then again, why would you want to copy the reference?

Comment: Internet Explorer: You never know what it will do next to mess you up.

Comment: Why Copy the Reference: To be more effective with JavaScript compilers and to make code easier to read when working with HTML attributes that contain code for JavaScript events.

Comment: @George Bailey: how does copying reference make it more effective with JS compilers? Also, when you handle html element events, you usually specify a js method, and inside the method you put the logic, not directly in the html event handlers - that is not required but a good practice

Comment: @George Bailey: Also, using built in methods directly makes the code way more readable

Comment: It does not work in Chrome. See my edit for responses to the rest of your comments.

Comment: @George - you are right, you actually shouldn't be doing this kind of aliasing, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 0):

Well, it happens that it does not even work in Chrome. I suppose I could have tested it before posting up here. I get `TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

The alternative is instead of

```
var byId = document.getElementById
```

just use

```
function byId(a) {return document.getElementById(a)}
```

This is not as efficient,, but it is shorter and many compilers will have no trouble at all converting

```
function getElementById(id) {return document.getElementById(id)}
```

into

```
function q(a){return document.getElementById(a)}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Andrey: I now know that the reason the first example did not work was because I was changing `document.getElementById` to `window.getElementById`.

The following works in my test and based on what I am reading, it should work everywhere.

```
var d = document
d.i = d.getElementById
```

Comment: it expects "this" inside the getElementById method call to be document, but it is "window" when you call it as byID(), so it fails

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out that the compiler benefit is not useful in the event you are using gzip. gzip already has deduplication built in while looking for any string. So if every instance of document had a dot after it it would deduplicate the dot also.

In fact, if you have a variable with a string in it, Google Closure Compiler will -- by default -- replace all references to the variable with the string itself and remove the variable and assume that it will have made a profit with gzip's help.

See: https://groups.google.com/group/closure-compiler-discuss/browse_thread/thread/857bdaa095a8685e