# JavaScript: Referencing host function via local variable

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Why doesn't this work?

```
function foo() {

    var g = document.getElementById;

    g('sampleID');

}
```

This error is thrown in Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`
... and in Firefox: `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"`

It works in IE9 beta though !!

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ugBpc/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Have you tried, `g.call(document, 'sampleID');` ??

Comment: @Pointy No, I didn't think ahead :)

Comment: @Pekka I voted to close this. Is that OK? I don't want to delete it since I'm afraid that that would remove it from my list of questions, and I'd like to keep this question.

Comment: @Šime yeah, absolutely! Your example is *way* better than the one in the other question, do keep this around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers require that the `document.getElementById` method is called in the context of the original object (`document`).  So this would work:

```
function foo() {      
    var g = document.getElementById;      
    g.call(document, 'sampleID');  
}
```

This will fail in Internet Explorer 7 and lower, however, because DOM methods don't inherit from `Function.prototype`.  Your original example should work in all versions of Internet Explorer.

You could also use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), in browsers that support it or where you have provided the [compatibility implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility):

```
function foo() {      
    var g = document.getElementById.bind(document);      
    g('sampleID');  
}
```

Comment: +1. I'd advise against doing any of this though. If `document.getElementById()` is too long, just wrap it in a function with a shorter name rather than attempt to create a reference to a host method.

Comment: @Tim Down: agreed, I don't think it's necessary to use `bind` for something like this.  I tested performance a while ago and it was orders of magnitude slower in Chrome and Firefox (although I'm not sure why).

Comment: @Tim Yes, that would be the more reasonable way to go.