# why window[id] === document.getElementById( id )

Tags: javascript

I've noticed in several browsers, dom elements can be accessed simply by their id like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="chocolat"></div>
```

**JS**

```
alert(chocolat.id); //alerts "chocolat
chocolat; //points to the node
window.chocolat; //idem
chocolat === document.getElementById('chocolat'); // true
```

( test here: http://jsfiddle.net/GUUPT/ )
This will work on some versions of IE, on Chrome, but it won't on Firefox(5).

I'm curious where does this come from ? is it in the standards?

Comment: @Bergi: wtf ? this question is 3 years old and you didn't even mention which question this is a duplicate of

Comment: Yes, the question is old and the answer is outdated. The duplicate is linked in the box "*This question already has an answer here: …*" at the top of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- It is non-standard
- It was started by Internet Explorer (version 4 IIRC)
- IIRC it only works in Quirks mode if you are using the latest version of IE

Comment: Last but not least, it isn't useful. In only leads to incompatible and hard to debug code.

Comment: This is now part of the HTML5 standard. See: http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object