# What is the error in this program? It's showing uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript

I get the following error

> uncaught typeerror : object is not a function

in the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reverse</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="rev1">
Enter the string : <input type="text" name="str">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="rev1()" />
```

And this is the place where I found the error:

```
reverse of given string : <input type="text" name="res">
</form>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function rev1(){
//var a=rev1.str.value;
//document.write("hello");
alert("hello");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

Comment: Isn't the error quite obvious? You're trying to use a variable `number` as a function, while it's not a function. Ctrl+F `number()` should bring you to the right place.

Comment: To the two close-voters, how is this "Not Constructive"?

Comment: i get the error as object is not a function ..

Comment: @user1560820 Always make sure to include the actual error. The error you posted first led in a different direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the form, or remove it altogether. `rev1` references the `form` element in your given script.

Demos: [**Original**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3PwR7/1/) - [**Working**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3PwR7/2/)
(click in the button to call the function directly)

Edit: I've seen this matter raise many discussions, so I'll leave some references as well:

- A notable question answered by Bobince: [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1331430) (this also applies in Firefox now, by the way)
- Another related question: [Directly reference HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7826737/1331430)