# do I really need to call getElementById()?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

I just stumbled upon an unexpected but useful behavior in the browser: It creates a variable for every element that has an ID in my html code. So when I have:

```
<div id="ohlala"> ... </div>
```

the browser seem to run this code behind the scene:

```
var ohlala = document.getElementById("ohlala");
```

so I can easily change the text of that element by:

```
ohlala.innerHTML="test"
```

Try it online: http://jsfiddle.net/Facby/
The question is: why would I need to write the `document.getElementById()` bit myself? How portable is that code? I tried in Opera, FireFox and Chrome and it works! Can I rely on this functionality? Does the browser always create variables for every element with id? In that case I have to be more careful about the names that are used in my javascript code not to conflict with similar ids from the HTML, right?

Comment: That's common, but AFAIK not standard. It started all in Internet Explorer, as you may imagine. IIRC older Firefox versions don't support it, and I don't know anything about it for mobile browsers.

Comment: Also, you have a lot of pre-existing properties on the `window` object, defining elements with ids matching those properties won't replace them on the `window` object and you will find yourself in a situation where you either have to avoid certain ids, or use `getElementById` _only_ for certain ids.

Comment: it will be problem in multiple forms .where we sometime use document.form[].element

Comment: I checked it for Firefox 3.6 and it doesn't work. By the way, did you test if it works when you dynamically append elements to the DOM? It's ok in IE and Chrome, don't know about the others.

Comment: DUPLICATE OF http://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1085285   http://stackoverflow.com/q/7826737/1085285

Comment: the problem (except that this is very bad practice) is that you will mix up variables like @lanzz said. how do you know what `ohlaha` was? you will have to guess

Comment: yeah for the sake of code readability it's better to avoid that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating elements with IDs, the "window" object receives the specific attributes, that's why you can use variables directly, this behavior is deprecated and usually is wrote like this: `window.ohlala.innerHTML = "..."`, this behavior is conserved by the browsers for compatibility with some older code on websites, but it is not recommended to use it in modern websites, always use .getElementById() method, this method is part of a W3C Standard, and you can use it in all modern browsers, in some very old browser versions and < IE7 it will not work. Learn more about DOM (Document Object Model) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

Comment: Which specific W3C standard would that be?

Comment: Can you point to the document, where this behavior is standardized?

Comment: You can find all W3C standards here: http://w3c.org getElementById was introduced in DOM Level 1 for HTML documents and moved to all documents in DOM Level 2: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId

Comment: @micnic You noticed that the question did not concern  `document.getElementById()`, but the implicit generation of a variable in the dom by the browser WITHOUT having to call `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: @micnic Ok, I think you misunderstood the question. Feel free to delete your answer...

Comment: @MaxArt I'm not a Windows user and I don't know for sure the versions were it doesn't work in IE, IE6 doesn't support it 100%.

Comment: @MaxArt, I will improuve my answer :)

Comment: @micnic IE6 has an odd bug with `getElementById` that returns elements with the matching `name` property too, instead of `id` only, but somehow it *is* supported. Also, improving the answer will be good, but I can't imagine how. Surprise me :)

Comment: I looked at the document, but it doesn't mention this behavior: the browser is creating a variable for every named element automatically.

Comment: @AlexStack, I'm very sorry, I have misunderstood your question, I edited my answer, `window.newVar` is the same `newVar` that's why you can access it in global context, but this is a deprecated behavior

Comment: @micnic This behavior is now a part of HTML5 spec:http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#named-access-on-the-window-object
It is called "Named access on the Window object": http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-document-nameditem

Comment: @AlexStack I'd still advise agains relying on it, as the standards document you have referred explicitly warns that "Browser vendors are considering limiting this behaviour to quirks mode"

Comment: @AlexStack Read carefully, that's not the same thing. The behaviour you were referring to is about *generic* DOM elements that create `window` properties identified by their `id`s. The link you've given deals with properties on the `document` object that matches some corrisponding 'named' items (explained some lines after that).