# Chrome console.log(elementID) outputs the element in the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" />
<script>
    console.log(password);
</script>
```

The code above outputs the following in the console:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
```

Noticed this when I outputted a variable `password` and noticed the HTML was prepended. Is that normal behaviour? What do we have `getElementById` for in that case?

Answer (score 4):

Getting an element using `window[element id]` or `window[element name]`  is [standard behavior](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) implemented by all modern browsers [since Firefox 14](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622491). I'll refer you to a few posts on the subject. As you'll find in most posts about the matter, use of the behaviour is not recommended and generally slower as browsers optimize `.getElementById` and checking if a variable is an id or name is the [lowest priority in global scope](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11960#c12).

- [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here#answer-3434388)
- [Can I use the id of an HTML element as a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776533/can-i-use-the-id-of-an-html-element-as-a-variable-in-javascript/19776660#19776660)

Answer (score 3):

Legacy behaviour is to define all elements with IDs (and names, I think) as properties of `window`. Therefore, `window.password` (or just `password`) could in theory be used as a shortcut for `getElementById`. However as soon as you define a variable with that same name, you get unpredictable behaviour.

This is one reason why global variables are bad. Always define your variables locally with `var`.

Comment: Aha right, I need to define them with `var`, been programming too much in `PHP` lately! :)