# Is js makes id of elem into variable automatically?

Tags: javascript

Recently when I writing js code, I found something..

1. I didn't define a variable which refers element using its id.
2. And I gave an event to that id.
3. It worked!!! without defining variable using "document.getElementById('id')"

For example :

```
html : 
<div id="abc"></div>

console :
abc;

console result :
<div id="abc"></div>
```

Why this happening? I didn't define variable 'abc' which refers div#abc.

ps. This happens not in ie. it happens in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting an element using window[element id] or window[element name] is standard behavior implemented by all modern browsers since Firefox 14.
[See More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918588/chrome-console-logelementid-outputs-the-element-in-the-console)