# why and how does jQuery use an undeclared variable as an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where is the documentation that explains why/how this works? jQuery interprets an undeclared variable as an id. I find this odd, and encountered by chance. How does it work?

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

   <input id="a" value="click" type="button" />

</div>
```

JS

```
$(wrapper).on("click", "#a", function(){

  alert("test");

});
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/iJETIlo/1/edit)

Comment: That's a quirk of JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: Here's a hint: it has nothing to do with jquery.

Comment: @zzzzBov: That's a quirk of Microsoft Internet Explorer, not JavaScript. :P

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776533/can-i-use-the-id-of-an-html-element-as-a-variable-in-javascript

Comment: @Amadan, all browsers do it, not just IE. It's a quirk of the language for backwards compatibility.

Comment: It's been standard in all browsers since ff 14.0

Comment: All browsers started doing it to make them compatible with IE's silliness. JavaScript outside browsers (like in Node.js), obviously, does not do this, so it cannot be a quirk of JavaScript.

Comment: @Amadan, i suppose to be more technically correct I should have said it's a quirk of a JavaScript module, but the point I was making was just that it was not a feature from jQuery.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I know. It was half joke, half jab at Microsoft in the Bad Old Days, and half hypercorrection. (It was a rather large comment. :D )

Comment: Maybe, of the DOM api is more appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't. Javascript/the DOM does.

The `id` attribute is used to create a global variable  that points to each element with an `id`.

This behaviour has been in Internet Explorer for years, and [is now standardised in HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-window-nameditem).