# How to paste data from clipboard to multiple input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I execute copy to clipboard with many inputs? I have this code

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="text" value="Hello" id="myInput1">
<input type="text" value="World" id="myInput2">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

**SCRIPT CODE**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText1 = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  var copyText2 = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  copyText1.select();
  copyText1.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you want to save these in the clipboard? Like, `myInput1myInput2` ?

Comment: @VermaJr. If possible, can I have it in this format:

"Description1: " myInput1
"Description2: " myInput2

Those with quotation marks are static, and each should be in new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a third input field (or a `textarea` if you also want to **add a newline character**) and simply hide it. And, just before executing the text select and copy commands, unhide the textarea and then again hide it.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var copyText1 = document.getElementById("myInput1");
    var copyText2 = document.getElementById("myInput2");
    var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
    hiddenInput.value = "Description1: " + copyText1.value + "\nDescription2: " + copyText2.value;
    hiddenInput.style.display = "";
    hiddenInput.select();
    hiddenInput.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    hiddenInput.style.display = "none";
    alert("Copied the text:\n" + hiddenInput.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello" id="myInput1">
<input type="text" value="World" id="myInput2">
<textarea id="hiddenInput" style="display:none;"></textarea>
    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: Working even if I need to hard code all @_@. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

maybe this one ?
for more clipboard usage info => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Using_the_Clipboard_API

```js
btCopy.onclick=_=>
  {
  // step 1: collect the input values (a method like so many others)
  let inputs = {}
  Array.from(new FormData(myForm),entry=>{inputs[ entry[0] ] = entry[1]})
  let All_inputs = JSON.stringify(inputs)

  // step 2 : write All_inputs into the clipboard
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(All_inputs)

  // as in your wishes...
  alert('Copied the text: ' + All_inputs)
  }
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="Description1" value="Hello">
  <input type="text" name="Description2" value="world">
</form>

<button id="btCopy">copy</button>
```

Comment: If you provide an explanation you'll likely get upvotes and accepts. And don't use the old way assuming an `id` exists as a variable, it is bad practice.

Comment: @LGSon You confuse what you call bad practice is just an opinion. In any case, Using names or IDs for elements has no incident for that code. For the record : I always use names for form elements family, because they are the ones used for serialization functions, not the IDs.

Comment: Then you might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19776647/2827823 ... and instead of take up on what is common known, you go against it. Another is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: Given that future users are supposed to learn from answers here, the most appropriate gets upvoted, other ones not, and I think you would want the same when you move into unknown areas of coding (get the more appropriate one's).

Comment: @LGSon and you should read this : https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener

Comment: Based on your link, it is clear you didn't read mine, so I'll rest my case.