# Can id attribute represent the element itself?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have come across a strange thing which I didn't find any reference for.
In JavaScript we use `document.getElementById("elem").value` to get the value of the element with the id="elem"

But I have seen some material which use `elem.value` straightway to get the value of the element with the id="elem". Previously I thought its a mistake, but when I use the code it works!!

Is it a valid code? How it works??

Please clarify.

Comment: Are you sure it's not calling value on a variable called `elem`? That would be my first guess.
Make a codepen! :)

Comment: I have implemented that in my own code, and it WORKS!!! Tested it with different elements as well!! NO variable was created by me.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826737/directly-reference-html-elements) SO question.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenHeier !!

Answer (score 0):

when you using a html form element it like this `<input type="text" id="name">`
then js collects this input type value  using`document.getElementById("elem").value`

Comment: Yap. But surprisingly `elem.value` also works. It returns the value of the "elem". Any idea why or how it works??

Comment: The value property sets or returns the value of the option (the value to be sent to the server when the form is submitted).

Comment: If the value property is not specified for an option element, then the text content will be sent to the server when the container form is submitted.