# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation on addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` for both versions of this attempt to put down an EventListener: (I get the error when the listener should be added, not when I click on the target)

`ronan.addEventListener("click", alert, false);`

`addEventListener.apply(ronan, ["click", alert, false]);`

`ronan` is a `div` element that is returned successfully by the console so I don't think that's the problem. Any ideas why I get this error? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work) thread and I couldn't figure it out from that.

Comment: maybe I should have waited til the morning to submit this

Comment: It might be the `alert`... native function. Does a blank `function(){}` work in its place?

Comment: @Artur Sapek Are you absolutely certain `ronan` is an HTMLDivElement? If so, can you post the code sets its value? Also, it would be nice if you could give a link to a demo page. By the way, *which* morning are talking about? It's currently morning in Europe and early in the morning in South America.

Comment: Also shouldn't the second line be `ronan.addEventListener.apply(...` instead of just `addEventListener.apply(...`?

Comment: @J-P nope, `addEventListener.apply` is short for `window.addEventListener.apply`.

Comment: @phihag, and won't that be why it's failing? The OP should call the `addEventListener` within the correct prototype, which happens to be `ronan.addEventListener`.

Comment: @J-P: The first argument of `apply` is the prototype, that's the point of `apply` as I understand it.
@phihag: The code invoking the element is code I'm using successfully in many other places in my JS. It's long and irrelevant, but when I enter `ronan` into the console I get in return:
`<div style=​"position:​ relative;​ top:​ 37px;​ left:​ 10px;​ margin-bottom:​ 5px;​ height:​ 37px;​ " id=​"bandRonan Delisle Quartet" class=​"all">​…​</div>​`

Comment: and I meant my own morning in Seattle, because I'm so sleepy I can barely think about this anymore

Comment: @Artur Sapek No offense, but why are you making possible answerer's lives so much harder by not providing any demo code (or a link to an example site)? By the way, note that there's no guarantee that `window.addEventListener == HTMLDivElement.addEventListener`. Therefore, the `apply` can still fail, and does so on Chrome and Firefox, precisely because `window.addEventListener != HTMLDivElement.addEventListener`. So J-P is right after all, to debug, you should write `ronan.addEventListener.apply ...`

Comment: You're all wrong about the second second line using `apply` - it should be `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener.apply(ronan, [function () { }]);`.

Comment: @Artur Sapek You didn't say which browser is producing this error. In [Internet Explorer prior to version 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer), you have to use `attachEvent` rather than `addEventListener`.

Comment: @phihag, I thought I had provided all of the relevant code, short of making a fiddle. I was hoping someone would come along who's already familiar with this problem, I didn't expect anyone to try taking on this problem for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to wrap `alert` in a function. This will work:

```
ronan.addEventListener("click", function() { alert('Hi'); }, false);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbwHp/2/) for proof. Using `alert` alone doesn't work because when a listener is executed the value of `this` within that function is set to the object on which it is listening. For example, if you set a listener on `ronan`, within that listener `this === ronan`. This presents a problem for `alert` because that function expects `this` to be equal to `window`. You can work around this (no pun intended) by wrapping the function in another function or by binding it to whatever it expects `this` to be:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', alert.bind(window), false);
```

Don't forget that in IE < 9 you need to use `attachEvent` rather than `addEventListener`.

---

**A note on using `apply`/`call` with `addEventListener`**

Your second attempt won't work because you're trying to apply your arguments to `window.addEventListener`, as opposed to `HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener`, which is a different function altogether:

```
// This won't work
addEventListener.apply(ronan, ["click", alert.bind(window), false]);

// This will work
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener.apply(ronan, ['click', alert.bind(window), false]);
```

Comment: Oh, word, you're right. I'm in fact not even using the prototype object, just the base, but your method still worked without the prototype part. I probably should have been aware of bind() since my JS is so focused on the DOM. Thanks a lot for your time!