# Why does window.location.reload need to be wrapped in a function(){}?

Tags: javascript, air, webkit

I've written some code to add a button to the page:

```
var myButt = document.createElement('button');
myButt.onclick = window.location.reload;
myButt.innerText = 'Reload';

document.body.appendChild(myButt);
```

But it throws an error:

> TypeError: Type error

Wrapping it in a function fixes the problem:

```
myButt.onclick = function(){ window.location.reload(); };
```

But my question is why the former doesn't work?

Executing `air.trace(typeof(window.location.reload));` outputs `function`.

[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11720212/1563422) from a high-rep user suggests that it should be possible. It's definitely more succinct.

I am running Adobe AIR 3.6 (which runs Webkit), if that makes a difference.

Comment: "Using `window.location.reload` alone doesn't work because when a listener is executed the value of `this` within that function is set to the object on which it is listening". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213369/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-addeventlistener

Comment: There's a subtle difference between a function that is just a function and a function which thinks it is a method. The difference is `this` and the value of `this` (usually) depends on how the function is called. @KevinBeal: You might want to expand that comment into an answer.

Comment: @KevinBeal Changing my code to `myButt.onclick = window.location.reload.bind(window.location);` now throws this error: *TypeError: instanceof called on an object with an invalid prototype property* (using [the MDN `bind` compatibility function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility))

Comment: If you look carefully at the code of the high-rep user you're referring to, you'll see that's not the case. That person's code has `el.onclick = forgotpass;`. Notice that `forgotpass` is **itself** a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` value is incorrect when using it like that.
`this` turns out to be `myButt` when you need it to be `window.location`.

To fix this *(hehe)*, either wrap it as you've done, or bind a new `this` value to it:

```js
myButt.onclick = window.location.reload.bind(window.location);
```

I just tested that, and it works on Firefox 23.0.1.

---

For future reference, he was using the `Function.prototype.bind` compatibility code found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

With my code above, he was getting the error

> TypeError: instanceof called on an object with an invalid prototype
>   property

To fix this, I changed line 18 of that compatibility code to the following:

```js
fNOP.prototype = this.prototype || {};
```

This is so that the prototype gets set to a blank object, because `window.location.reload` doesn't have a prototype naturally.

Comment: As I commented above, that code throws *TypeError: instanceof called on an object with an invalid prototype property*

Comment: Ok, I see. On line 18 of that compatibility code, change the line to this: `fNOP.prototype = this.prototype || {};`

Comment: The reason for doing that is because "window.location.reload" has no prototype property, so it fails in `.bind()`

Comment: But I got my answer anyway - because of the binding to `this`. Feel free to debug further if you wish to, but this is good enough!

Comment: Hmm.. must be your browser. I just used the compatibility code, with the fix, with my code above for setting the onclick, and it works fine. Which browser are you on?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38066/discussion-between-joe-simmons-and-danny-beckett)

Comment: For future reference for anyone else: Joe's comment of adding `|| {}` makes this work perfectly!!