# Simple AJAX jQuery not executing until Developer Tools Activated - Firefox & Chartist.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging, firefox, chartist.js

I've seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095348/website-with-js-doesnt-work-in-ie9-until-the-developer-tools-is-activated) about this topic but never seen this happen in Firefox. I'm using Firefox 49.0.2 on a modern mac running Yosemite.

My code that I just added which is holding up until I open the Developer Console:

```
            var jsonSeries = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.simplymeasured.com/v1/analytics/<account-id>/profiles/metrics?filter=profile.id.eq(<numbers>)&filter=analytics.timeseries_key.gt(2016-10-01)&dimensions=analytics.timeseries_key.by(day)',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer <a long key>',
                    'Content': 'application/json',
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store'
                    },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
            }).done(function(json) {
                for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
                    jsonSeries.push(json.data[i]['attributes']['metrics']["analytics.audience_count"]);
                }
            });

            var dataCT = {
              labels: ['W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10'],
              series: [
                jsonSeries
              ]
            };

            var optionsCT = {
              axisX: {
                labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
                  return index % 2 === 0 ? value : null;
                }
              }
            };

            new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', dataCT, optionsCT);
```

The chart initialized afterwards even loads fine, it's just empty. Even if my Developer Console is open initially, the actual data won't appear until I simply resize the Developer Console. It seems like *any* trigger or action on the Developer Console will bring in the data.

---

With developer console initially open, reloading the page, even waited 10+ seconds just in case:
[image: ajax data not working until developer console resized]

---

After resizing developer console only a few pixels:
[image: after resizing developer console - ajax jquery]

Comment: out of curiosity is this happening only when console is opened/resized or the window too? Opening/resizing the console technically triggers this same event. Perhaps it's something to do with some rendering that only happens on window resize.

Comment: It's the window too... didn't even think about. That opens up quite a few more places it could have gone wrong. Without knowing my code, is there some key things I should be looking for?

Comment: I can't see the whole code, but I would start looking for "resize" event listeners. Other than that I'd be as lost as you man. sorry :( Actually... is there an event you can manually trigger when the ajax update is done that three.js recognizes?