# Javascript creating references to native functions

Tags: javascript

I have written this code (this is a snippet) that doesn't seem to be working. I have isolated it to here.

```
grab = window.document.getElementById;
grab("blueBox") // i.e. grab("blueBox").onclick [...]
```

Is it possible to create references to native function in javascript. I am doing something with the grabbed element, I just left it out for example. The grab function doesn't seem to work.

I am using FireFox's most recent version

Comment: It's not working, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementById` is a **host** function. Native functions are the built–ins (like Array, Object, etc.) and any function created by ECMAScript code (e.g. `function foo(){...}`, `var bar = function(){...}`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Live test case with the `apply` workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/N4Ghd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're doing it will mess up the assignment of the `this` value for the function.

```
grab = window.document.getElementById;
grab("blueBox") // i.e. grab("blueBox").onclick [...]
```

here `this` will be the `global` object. Try:

```
grab.apply(window.document, ["blueBox"])
```

or in newer browsers:

```
grab = window.document.getElementById.bind(window.document);
```

to get directly define what `this` will be.

Comment: @Yoshi—Nothing whatever to do with scope, everything to do with the function's *this* keyword.

Comment: @RobG You're correct, it's a very bad habit of mine to always mix the wording when trying to explain it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function grab(id) {
    return window.document.getElementById(id);
}

grab("blueBox");
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step here is always the JavaScript console. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is your friend. Tell us the error message if it doesn't mean anything to you.

In the mean time, here is a workaround:

```
var grab = function(id) { return window.document.getElementById(id); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the function `getElementById` is not being called as a method of `document`, so its *this* keyword doesn't reference the right object. Using *call* as suggested in other answers shows that when *this* references the document, `getElementById` works.