# addEventListener not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, addeventlistener

I have created a checkbox dynamically. I have used `addEventListener` to  call a function on click of the checkbox, which works in Google Chrome and Firefox but **doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8**. This is my code:

```
var _checkbox = document.createElement("input");
_checkbox.addEventListener("click", setCheckedValues, false);
```

`setCheckedValues` is my event handler.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Try:

```
if (_checkbox.addEventListener) {
    _checkbox.addEventListener("click", setCheckedValues, false);
}
else {
    _checkbox.attachEvent("onclick", setCheckedValues);
}
```

**Update::**
For Internet Explorer versions prior to IE9, [attachEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) method should be used to register the specified listener to  the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) it is called on, for others [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) should be used.

Comment: A description as to why this should be used will improve the answer.

Comment: @dkris added a short description as a clarification, i hope that makes things a bit clearer.. :)

Answer (score 44):

You have to use `attachEvent` in IE versions prior to IE9. Detect whether `addEventListener` is defined and use `attachEvent` if it isn't:

```
if(_checkbox.addEventListener)
    _checkbox.addEventListener("click",setCheckedValues,false);
else
    _checkbox.attachEvent("onclick",setCheckedValues);
//                         ^^ -- onclick, not click
```

Note that [IE11 will remove `attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacyAPIs).

See also:

- [MDN: `element.addEventListener`: Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)
- [MSDN: attachEvent method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

This is also simple  crossbrowser solution:

```
var addEvent =  window.attachEvent||window.addEventListener;
var event = window.attachEvent ? 'onclick' : 'click';
addEvent(event, function(){
    alert('Hello!')
});
```

Instead of 'click' can be any event of course.

Comment: +1, I think this is a smart workaround! `addEventListener`'s third argument is optional anyway, so this can be a good solution, and it's nicer than the if-else branches. But in this case, `_checkbox` is the target element, not `window`. :) So maybe you could create a function where the event target is another argument.

Comment: Oh, I upvoted too early... :) I get a _"TypeError: Illegal invocation"_ in Chrome if I try to alias event target elements' `addEventListener` calls - see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work. So for the `window` object, it works correctly, but does not work for other nodes inside the document. This way your suggested aliasing is NOT correct for the case mentioned in the original question! What would be your workaround?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below addEvent() function to add events for most things but note that for XMLHttpRequest `if (el.attachEvent)` will fail in IE8, because it doesn't support `XMLHttpRequest.attachEvent()` so you have to use `XMLHttpRequest.onload = function() {}` instead.

```
function addEvent(el, e, f) {
    if (el.attachEvent) {
        return el.attachEvent('on'+e, f);
    }
    else {
        return el.addEventListener(e, f, false);
    }
}

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onload = function(e) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IE doesn't support `addEventListener` until version 9, so you have to use `attachEvent`, here's an example:

```
if (!someElement.addEventListener) {
    _checkbox.attachEvent("onclick", setCheckedValues);
}
else {
    _checkbox.addEventListener("click", setCheckedValues, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mayb it's easier (and has more performance) if you delegate the event handling to another element, for example your table

```
$('idOfYourTable').on("click", "input:checkbox", function(){

});
```

in this way you will have only one event handler, and this will work also for newly added elements. This requires jQuery >= 1.7

Otherwise use delegate()

```
$('idOfYourTable').delegate("input:checkbox", "click", function(){

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've opted for a quick Polyfill based on the above answers:

```
//# Polyfill
window.addEventListener = window.addEventListener || function (e, f) { window.attachEvent('on' + e, f); };

//# Standard usage
window.addEventListener("message", function(){ /*...*/ }, false);
```

Of course, like the answers above this doesn't ensure that `window.attachEvent` exists, which may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can write:

```
$( _checkbox ).click( function( e ){ /*process event here*/ } )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("click", attachEvent, false);
}
else {
    document.attachEvent("onclick", attachEvent);
}
function attachEvent(ev) {
    var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
    // custom code
}
```