# Getting selected value without using onchange attribute

Tags: javascript, select, onchange, selectedvalue

I want the same result without using the `onchange` attribute.
Some ideas?

Here's the HTML:

```
<select onchange="filtro(this)" id="tipo" name="noticia/conteudo/tipo">
    <option  value="Layout1">Layout1</option>
    <option value="Layout2">Layout2</option>
    <option value="Layout3">Layout3</option>
    <option value="Layout4">Layout4</option>
    <option value="Layout5">Layout5</option> 
</select>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function filtro(a) {
    var x = (a.value || a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);
    alert(x);
    if (x == "Layout4"){
        alert('test4');
    } 
}
```

Comment: If not on change, when?

Comment: I want ecxatly what the code are doing but without using the onchange attirbute inside of the select tag with the function inside

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to avoid having the onchange attribute.

HTML:

```
<select id="tipo" name="noticia/conteudo/tipo">
    <option value="Layout1">Layout1</option>
    <option value="Layout2">Layout2</option>
    <option value="Layout3">Layout3</option>
    <option value="Layout4">Layout4</option>
    <option value="Layout5">Layout5</option> 
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function filtro(a) {
    var x = (a.value || a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);
    alert(x);
    if (x == "Layout4"){
        alert('test4');
    } 
}

var sel = document.getElementById('tipo');
sel.addEventListener('change', function() { filtro(sel) }, false);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/HfmWV/7/

Comment: Solution found it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 1):

you can do it on easy way

```
var e = document.getElementById("tipo");
var tipoValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Would make tipoValue be value of selected option.
In case that you would like to get text you can do it with:

```
var e = document.getElementById("tipo");
var tipoText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

In general my suggestion is to consider introduction of some javascript library, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this only in js without attribute

```
document.getElementById("id").onchange=function(){ ... };
```