# Hammer.js (IE8)- Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch, hammer.js

I'm using hammer.js for a touch menu for a site, and getting:

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'"
>   hammer.js, line 247 character 13

with IE8.

The actual code from hammer.js that is not working:

```
/**
 * simple addEventListener
 * @param   {HTMLElement}   element
 * @param   {String}        type
 * @param   {Function}      handler
 */
bindDom: function(element, type, handler) {
    var types = type.split(' ');
    for(var t=0; t<types.length; t++) {
        element.addEventListener(types[t], handler, false);
    }
},
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Jquery used to have a similar issue:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11127

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8, try to fix the code and eventually pull a request to the developers.

Comment: You don't need to make a pull, you should use the jquery version to IE8/IE7 support.

Comment: "you should use the jquery version" - Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from here: [addEventListener not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8)

You can fix the code function by checking the definition of `addEventListener` like :

```
bindDom: function (element, type, handler) {
    var types = type.split(' ');
    for (var t = 0; t < types.length; t++) {
        if (!element.addEventListener) {
            element.attachEvent(types[t], handler);
        } else {
            element.addEventListener(types[t], handler, false);
        }
    }
},
```

if it works we can eventually pull a request to the developers.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

If you need support for IE8 or IE7 you should use the jquery version of Hammer plugin. You can download it [here](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/tree/v1.0.5/dist).

Comment: from what I understand, you still need Hammer.js with jquery.hammer.js. The error is inside Hammer.js so that wouldnt solve the error.

Comment: So you don't understand :D, the Hammer.js has two version... one is pure JavaScript and don't support IE8 and IE7 (hammer.js), the other one is a jquery plugin version of the hammer.js and support IE8/IE7 just take a look on compatibility table https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: He does understand thank you very much this cost me an hour. The jQuery version doesn't work either giving this error: SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action  which i suspect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. 
https://github.com/egjs/hammerjs-compatible

```html
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/hammerjs.compatible.js"></script> <- like this.
<![endif]-->
<script src="../bower_components/hammer.js/hammer.js"></script>
```