# Socket.io on connect fires many times on IE 8 on WinXP

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer-8, socket.io, windows-xp

When I connect to the node server on IE 8 under WinXP, the `connect` event is fired many times. When I do the same on Chrome under WinXP or IE 11 under Windows 7 the `connect` fires only once, as expected.

The client code:

```
if (that.debug && window.console) console.log('connecting to '+server_addr);
var socket = that.socket = io.connect(server_addr,{
    'reconnect' : false,
    'connect timeout' : 1000,
    'max reconnection attempts': 3
});

socket.on('connect', function(){
    if (that.debug && window.console) console.log('Socket.on event:  connect');
    cb.call(that,socket);
});
```

The output on IE 8 :

```
LOG: connecting to my_server.com
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
LOG: Socket.on event:  connect
```

Anyone experienced this issue? any idea how to solve / debug this?

Comment: You might be duplicating listeners. If it suits your design, try calling `socket.removeAllListeners()` before each emit. But I don't think the problem is within this code. Have any more?

Comment: The 'connecting to' error is displayed only once and there aren't any other places in the code where I connect or add more listeners without writing to the console, so I really don't think that this is the case. Morever, on other platforms / browsers the 'connect' is fired only once. Nevertheless I will try removing all listeners as you suggested just to varify that this is not the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket.IO and IE8 - jsonp-polling connections always failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637953/socket-io-and-ie8-jsonp-polling-connections-always-failing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We continued experiencing this issue on some computers, I suspect it had to do with the WiFi router installed.

We finally got it resolved by upgrading to [socket.io](http://socket.io/) version 1.0:

```
if (that.debug && window.console) console.log('connecting to '+server_addr);
var socket = io.connect(server_addr);
socket.on('connect', function(){
    if (that.debug && window.console) console.log('Socket.on event:  connect');
    cb.call(that,socket);
});
```

Hope it will help anyone else having similar issues.