# addEventListener issue to redirect in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, addeventlistener

I have 2 pages 'a' and 'b' and the default page is 'a'. If there is no mouse movement, i will automatically redirect to page 'b'. To do this, I used the following code:

```
var initTime = null;
function timeOutFunction() {    
    initTime = setTimeout(function() {window.location = 'b';}, 5000);
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', timeOutFunction, true);
```

The above code is working fine for IE 10 / IE 11. But does not working on IE 8. To make it workable into IE 8, is there any solution?

For IE 8, I also tried using the following code:

```
window.attachEvent("mousemove", timeOutFunction);
```

but still not working :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [addEventListener not working in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8) (and any number of other IE8/`addEventListener` questions as shown under the "Related" heading on the right of this page). Also, should your `initTime` variable not be called `timer` to match what you use within `timeOutFunction`?

Comment: Regarding your edit, with .attachEvent() - which works only in IE - the event name needs to be "onmousemove" rather than "mousemove".

Comment: You have to use attachEvent only for IE8, for rest of the browser you can proceed with addEventListener as I answered.

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` is supported from version 9 onward . For older versions use the similar `attachEvent` function.

You can use `addEventListener` for IE version 9 and higher and for IE8 `attachEvent`.

Please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I tried using window.attachEvent("mousemove", timeOutFunction) but still not working.