# Pc name in url will set error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

My ASP/AngularJS web site is hosted in a local machine.
If I access to it via IE11 by ip that works.
If I visit by name I get an error on jquery-2.1.1.js  [3425]:

```
document.addEventListener("DocumentLoaded", completed, false);

'addEventListener' not supported
```

In Firefox everything is working fine.

Comment: please share your javascript in jsfiddle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the two configurations sending different headers.

Assuming you are running IIS there are a couple of different pages which describe things here.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Future readers, my apologies, but I don't know enough to begin to summarize those pages here, but it involves setting the `X-UA-Compatible` value, both as an HTTP header and in the `HEAD` section of the HTTP document itself.