# How can I support window.addEventListener in IE 8 without modifying the source of a script?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, addeventlistener

I try to animate header in IE8 but i see error "Invalid procedure call or argument"

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}
```

I wound similar solution here ( [addEventListener not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8) ) but i can't modify my source....

Comment: Try a polyfill https://github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener

Comment: This is not supported below IE9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: *"i can't modify my source"* Huh? Sorry, that requires explanation. As far as I can tell, this is a simple duplicate of the question you've linked to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it means exactly that, OP can't change the code of the function. Like elclanrs said, a polyfill is needed here.

Comment: @Stijn: But that would require modifying things, too.

Comment: @elclanrs: The question is vague at best, but your point might actually be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no, it would require loading an additional file, before this script is executed.

Comment: @Stijn: And how do you propose loading an additional file without changing something? I didn't say he had to change his *JavaScript*, I said that would require modifying things (specifically, the HTML).

Comment: @mplungjan: (It wasn't from me.)

Comment: @mplungjan indeed, don't make such assumptions. I downvoted your answer because it modifies the function.

Answer (score 1):

So that you have an answer you can accept, summarizing the comments:

- If you can modify your JavaScript code (despite what it says in the question), you can use the techniques in the answers to [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8) to hook the event.
- If you can modify your HTML but not your JavaScript, you can add a script prior to your existing one that adds a polyfill to IE to make `addEventListener` available. [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs) pointed to [this one](https://github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener).
- If you can't do either of those things, there's nothing you can do.