# Transform Facebook fb:login-button into SDK javascript login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need a custom facebook login button. The fb:login-button solution with medium, large etc. is not what I need. I know the FB TOS. My button will be very similiar.

How is it possible to tranform my button into a javascript onlick solution with a custom button? The "onlogin="top.location.href='example.com/facebook_connect.php" link is very important.

Here my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#appId=myappid6&xfbml=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">  FB.init({
appId  : myappid,
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
</script>


<fb:login-button scope="email, public_profile" size="xlarge" onlogin="top.location.href='example.com/facebook_connect.php'">Connect with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<button id="loginBtn">Facebook Login</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do the login
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            top.location.href = 'example.com/facebook_connect.php';
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,public_profile', return_scopes: true});
}, false);
```

Source: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Don´t use a-tags for this, it´s not a link. You don´t need jQuery either, it´s just a simple click handler. I suggest using the asynchronous way to load the JS SDK though.

Comment: awesome. thank you very much. Works like a charm :)
Is this fit for the facebook 2015 login changes?

Comment: this did not change at all in the last few years (except for return_scopes, not sure if that´s newer), i am pretty sure it will work in the same way next year ;)

Comment: the important changes for next year are mostly about login permissions, that´s another story (review and stuff).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I mean this notice from facebook you too?:  At f8 2014, we launched a new Facebook Login experience that gives people more control over the information they share with apps. The new Login contains significant differences from the version you have today and will need to be implemented before the breaking change date on April 30, 2015. To ensure enough time for your users to upgrade to the latest version of your mobile app, we recommend you start upgrading today.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/

Comment: i believe that´s mostly about native mobile apps, but i doubt that the login process in the js sdk will change.

Comment: We will see and at least we can use the default way. thank you for your time...maybe we read us again anytime.

Comment: If found one problem with IE8. This browser have a problem with document.getElementById. Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: it´s not about getElementById, IE8 does not support addEventListener. IE8 does not really matter anymore (and you actually should stop supporting it imho), but if you really want to support it, it´s easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 0):

I have used my custom button that hides default facebook login button. See if it helps.

```
<div class="img_container">
     <a class="btnFacebookLogin" href="#" role="button">
       <span class="img_icon icon_facebook" title="Facebook"></span>
       <div class="fb-login-button" onlogin="javascript:CallAfterLogin();" width="200" size="medium" autologoutlink="true" scope="user_education_history,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_hometown,user_likes,email,user_checkins,user_groups,friends_groups,user_photos,user_events,user_location,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_religion_politics,user_website,user_work_history,user_interests,user_about_me"
           style="display: none;">
       </div>
     </a>
 </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnFacebookLogin').on('click', function () {
        FB.login(function (response) { CallbackAfterLogin(response); }, { scope: 'email' });
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.img_container
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.img_icon
{
   display: block;
   width: 42px;
   height: 42px;
}


.icon_facebook
{
    background-image: url("../Images/Icons/social.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 172px 84px;
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
}
```

You can adjust the CSS according to your custom image. I allowed 'login with' option for multiple sites like Twitter, g+; etc. So I used a single image that has all the necessary icons.

Comment: where do I have to display the redirect uri? could you please update your code. Thank you

Comment: you don´t need to specify the redirect uri with FB.login, you just redirect in the callback. but i have to say that hiding the login button is a very bad way. i mean...as i see it, the button just does nothing at all, it´s just hidden and you could also just delete it from your html.

Comment: works too, I decided me for the other solution. thank you very much