# Making postMessage() and addEventListener() compatible with IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, addeventlistener, postmessage

I'm working on a project where we need to use both `postMessage()` and `addEventListener()`, but we want to make the application compatible with major browsers. Because there are still people (yes they exist, and yes they should be burned) using Internet Explorer 8, we need to make the above two methods compatible.

I've written the code below, which takes care of making `addEventListener()` compatible by using `attachEvent()` instead as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9769930/4274852). However, `postMessage()` is still not working and therefore I added in a timeout, as suggested on [this website](http://www.felocity.com/article/window_postmessage_problems_and_workarounds_for_ie8/). This does not work, and I'm really struggling making the application compatible. It does not throw any errors, and I can also see my application has send a message to the iframe source, however the message is never handled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ready()
    {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("editor").contentWindow.postMessage("A", "domain here");
        }, 0);
    }

    function receiveMessage(event)
    {
        if (event.origin !== "domain here")
            return;
    }

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
        }
        else {
            window.attachEvent("message", receiveMessage);
        }
    }, 0);
</script>
```

I have a similar script on my second page (which is being loaded in an iframe) which receives a message and sends a message back. Both messages are being send and received by all major browsers, so the question is: How can I make above script compatible with Internet Explorer 8?

Once again: I agree we should not care about people using Internet Explorer 8, and should instead burn them for still using it: However that would mean we would've to burn our clients, something we cannot do. So yes, I really need to make it compatible.

In case you are wondering: `getElementById("editor")` catches an iframe defined as follows:

```
<iframe src="frameListener.html" class="editor" id="editor" onload="ready()"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "on"

```
window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);
```

Comment: Yea ignore my previous comment, I forgot to add it in on both pages: Now it works :) However I'm receiving a different error now, so I'll be bugfixing that. Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer as it fixed my original issue.