# Using debounce function with parse-time function declaration syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to debounce keystrokes in a form input on IE Mobile 6 (from what I gather, about on par with IE 3-4 in terms of support).

Due to the lack of support, I can't add event listeners after declaration (i.e., `document.getElementById('elementId').addEventListener(...)` doesn't work), I can only do them inline, like `onkeydown="doSomething()"`.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/xotenimipa/1/edit?html,js,console,output) is a jsBin.

So, with this debounce function (taken from [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)):

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
```

The recommended way to set up your event function would be like:

```
var doSomething = debounce(function() { ... }, 250);
```

However, I can't use this `doSomething` style function in the inline event listeners on IE Mobile 6.

So, in the markup, I've tried:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="doSomething()" />
```

And

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="doSomething()()" />
```

And in javascript:

```
// return the result of debounce()
function doSomething() {
    return debounce(function() { ... }, 250);
}

// just debounce()
function doSomething() {
    debounce(function() { ... }, 250);
}

// return the result of the returned function of debounce, aka debounce()()
function doSomething() {
    return debounce(function() { ... }, 250)();
}
```

I've also just tried putting the whole contents of the debounce function inside of this function, like:

```
function doSomething() {
    var timeout, func, wait, immediate;

    func = function() {
        console.log('test');
    };

    wait = 250;

    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}
```

So, long question short:

How can I write this exact statement:

```
var doSomething = debounce(...);
```

Like this:

```
function doSomething() {

}
```

Comment: if you're doing `var doSomething = debounce(function() { ... }, 250);` outside a function, there's no reason you can't use it directly in `onkeydown="doSomething()"` so something else must be going on. If you're doing it in a function, you could try `window.doSomething = debounce(function() { ... }, 250);` to make it global

Comment: This seems excessive to do. Why not just tie into the oninput event?

Comment: Just a heads up @Tom, a little digging found a doc stating that IE Mobile 6 only supports ECMAScript 3 :[. I'm checking around to see if this might have something to do with your `document.getElementById()` and `addEventLIstener` issue...IE has always been a little flaky with its implementations of JS in the earlier years.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/c/c/8cc611e7-ec6b-49ee-af4a-415559d53262/Internet%20Explorer%20Mobile%206.pdf

Comment: Just in case you're not opposed to do some light reading, here's the ECMAScript 3 ref. I checked to see if the `.apply` call in the debounce method was an issue...didn't seem like it. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Comment: also, exactly what version are you using - seems like early 6.x versions didn't support keyboard events http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/05/14/internet-explorer-mobile-handles-key-events/

Comment: Try using `.attachEvent` instead of `.addEventListener`. Older implementations of IE browsers (< IE 9) use the attachEvent method. It looks like IE Mobile 6 borrows a lot of its technologies from IE 8, so that's suspect.

`document.getElementById("elementId").attachEvent("keydown", doSomething)`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a pretty unique situation. Given that your target browser (IE Mobile 6) implements pretty old technologies (ECMAScript 3 and elements from IE 8), you won't be able to use the standard `addEventListener` method. Part of your problem is likely due to a mixture of the context limitations of using inline javascript along with the fact that you're programming against an old, old (1999) version of JS. Let's see how this works.

**EDIT**
Also make sure you're wrapping your code in some kind of document ready. I'll use jQuery to do that. That could be why your JS isn't executing.

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='theInput' />
<script src='yourDebounceScript.js'></script>
```

JS

```
// by the time this is executed, 
// DOM elements above this script will be ready
(function() {
    function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function () {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    }

    var input = document.getElementById('theInput');
    input.attachEvent('keydown' function() {

        // wrap your debounce function in an anonymous function
        // so that you can pass arguments to the debounce as needed
        debounce(function() { /* ... */ }, 250, true);

    });
})();
```

If you can use jQuery:

```
// make sure the document is ready before trying to access the DOM
$(function() {

    // your debounce function here...

    // jQuery will handle the version compatibility for you
    $('#theInput').keydown(debounce);

});
```