# JavaScript onclick event not working in IE9 and below

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

As Foundation 5 does not support IE8, I am showing a warning message to upgrade the browser with CSS (`display:inline;`) in conditional tags `<!--[if lt IE 9]>`, which is hidden on all other browsers (`display:none;`).
This works as intended. The markup of the message is placed in the body:

```
<div id="ie8warning" class="ie8warning">
   <div>This site does not support <b>Internet Explorer 7 and 8.</b>
   <div id="closewarning">×</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Now, the message contains a small 'X' (`<div id="closewarning">×</div>`), which should close the window, when it is clicked. I wrote the following JavaScript, which works in all modern browsers. However, the `onclick`-event is obviously not recognized in IE9 and below. IE9 is not important as the message will not show up, but IE8 and below are essential:

```
function closeWarning() {
   var ie8Warning = document.getElementById('ie8-warning');
   ie8Warning.style.display = 'none';
}

var ie8Button = document.getElementById('closewarning');
ie8Button.onclick = closeWarning;
```

Would appreciate your advice how to get this working in pure JavaScript.

Comment: They do support it, so the problem is somewhere else. Where is your `<script>` tag/how are you waiting for the element to exist? Does any error appear in the console?

Comment: In addition to @minitech's comment, make sure that the 'x' button really is located where it is supposed to be on IE8-IE9. Inspect the page elements and make sure things are positioned in the right place.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9769930/5202773

Comment: error in the console?

Comment: try replacing your div element with an input or  button element.

Comment: Script is placed in app.js just before the closing body-tag. Using `window.onload = function () { ... }` to wait for the complete page to be loaded. Debug tool in IE8 throws only JS-errors related to Foundation 5 (which is unspported), but does not return any errors in app.js...

Comment: The placement of `#closewarning` is more interesting, is it in `head`?

Comment: No, it is placed in the body. Will add the exact markup to the question.

Comment: Could you add a few `console.log`s to check whether the `onclick` assignment runs at all and whether the event handler runs at all? Other errors might be stopping your code from running, or `window.onload` might be overwritten by something else… (note that you have to have the console open while loading the page for `console` to exist in old IEs).

Comment: When I run the original JS without the Foundation 5 JS, it works. The message closes. As IE8 cannot handle the Foundation JS, it obviously stops executing JS, which logically stops the event from being detected...What do you do in such a case? Put the script in the conditional tag in the head?

Comment: So my guess is the foundation code is causing your code to not get executed.

Comment: Try taking it out of `onload` as a first step; since your script is at the bottom of `<body>`, you don’t need to wait for any events to start using elements that exist in `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is a HTML4 browser, hyphens in `id`s are not allowed. An id in HTML4 browsers can contain any alphanumeric string that begins with a letter. The underscore (_) can also be used.

Comment: I stripped all hyphens from the IDs and changed the CSS and JS accordingly, but the problems persists. The message is not hiding on X click.

Comment: @user3046831 No? That's too bad. Have you checked that the onclick really is not fired (logged to the console/alerted sth in the handler)?

Comment: `id="ie8warning"` and `id="closewarning"` are unique on each page. Just used `monitorEvents(window);` in the Chrome console and onclick is clearly fired, when the X is clicked.

Comment: @user3046831: In IE 8, not in Chrome.

Comment: Running `monitorEvents(window);` in IE8 console throws an error: "Object expected".

Comment: The Foundation 5 JS throws errors in IE8, which stops the script from being executed. Putting the script in an extra file in the conditional tag executes the closing correctly.