# How to add "oninput" to html form tag, targeting the tag by id instead of editing the form tag itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use this code that I found online http://jsfiddle.net/2GhQX/
in my contact form in order to show the range slider values in real time, however, my form was created using a wordpress plugin, so I can't add any javascript to the `<form>` tag. The plugin does allow me to add id's and classes to the form tag though (plugin: contactform7).

Is there a way to add `oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value"` to the `<form>` tag, without editing the form tag itself by maybe targeting that form using an id or a class?

I know very very little about javascript, so I will appreciate the help.

So instead of

```
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
```

I want my form tag to look like this:

```
<form id="myform">
```

and then add the oninput to the tag targeting it by the form id using javascript

Comment: I think [addEventListener vs onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6348494/1529630) covers your question.

Comment: in pure javascript `document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('input', function(){//do your stuff here});`, in jQuery `$('#myform').on('input', function(){//your code here});`

Comment: also you can use `document.querySelector('#myform')` instead of `document.getElementById('myform')`.. and `bind` word instead of `on` in jQuery..  and keep in my mind `addEventListener` is not supported in IE8 and below you need to use `attachEvent` instead, check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8 for how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.getElementById()` method to get access to the form:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('my-form-id');
myForm.addEventListener('input
```

```js
var theForm = document.getElementById('theform');
theForm.addEventListener('input', function(){
  alert('hi');  
});
```

```html
<form id="theform">
  
  <input />
  
</form>
```