# I want to change the class of a particular element, can you please tell me why my code is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the class of a particular `<li></li>` element and I found a few ways to do so, but non of them worked, can you please tell me the reason why my code is not working >

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.header a[href="register_friend.php"]').parent().setAttribute("class", "active");
    </script>

<header class="header" >
    <nav><ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="register_friend.php">Register a friend</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Register Yourself</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Rate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I would like to add that I am using an external header, if that brings any change.

```
<body >
<div id="header"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Try putting the <script> underneath the header.

Comment: `setAttribute()` is a plain vanilla JS method and you're trying to use it on a jQuery object

Comment: Adding onto what @selten98 said, I think it's important to explain _why_. Your javascript is executing before your class `header` is loaded, therefore, it can't act on the class because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Also, what errors do you get in the console?

Comment: @j08691 unfortunately there is no error in the console, that's the main problem :P

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I changed the code a bit

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton 
[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEEbjj)

Comment: If you include jQuery and load the script properly, it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zdrnqojc/

Comment: What do you mean by "external header"?  Are you injecting the `<header>` html after page load?  If so, you need to make sure you're running this code after the DOM you're trying to modify has already been injected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    $('.header a[href="register_friend.php"]').parent().addClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

Look for  addClass in API documentation https://api.jquery.com/addClass/

https://codepen.io/codingonHP/pen/OggeJb

wrt to addEventListner : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded and for IE: 
[addEventListener not working in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8)

Comment: didn't work, also tried the addClass() function, is there some other way? :(

Comment: post your code again what you are running. Yes, the codepen link https://codepen.io/codingonHP/pen/OggeJb  is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap your script in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // Note:jquery use 'attr', instead of 'setAttribute' to set attribute.
    $('.header a[href="register_friend"]').parent().attr("class", "active");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to get the DOM node itself, so you can use the native `setAttribute`, or else use the jQuery `.attr()` on the jQuery object.  Either of these will work (assuming the DOM nodes exist at the time the script is run -- do usual document.ready dance if necessary.)

```js
// use the DOM node:
$('.header a[href="register_friend.php"]').parent()[0].setAttribute("class", "active");

// or use the jQuery object:
$('.header a[href="register_friend.php"]').parent().attr("class", "active");
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid #F00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="register_friend.php">Register a friend</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Register Yourself</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Rate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

If you know there will only be one matching element, those methods are equivalent. If you need to be able to handle more than one matching element, use the jQuery `.attr()` method which will apply to all nodes within the set.

(...but with that said, `.addClass()` is probably a safer choice than setting the class directly with `.attr()` or `.setAttribute()`, because the latter two will overwrite any the other classnames presently on the element.)

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `addClass`, not set the attribute.

Apart from that you should wrap the jQuery function into `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` if you want this to happen on page load:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.header a[href="register_friend.php"]').parent().addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header" >
    <nav><ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="register_friend.php">Register a friend</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Register Yourself</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Rate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```