# Code compiled by Parceljs is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, babeljs, parceljs

I have written the code in es6 format and compiled the code using **parceljs**. It is working fine in Chrome and not working in IE11. I am getting an error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Code written:

```
function startGame(){
    circleTurn = true;
    cellElements.forEach(cell=>{
        cell.addEventListener('click',handleClick,{once:true});
    });
    swapTurns();
}
```

After compilation code by parcel

```
function startGame() {
  circleTurn = true;
  cellElements.forEach(function (cell) {
    cell.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {
      once: true
    });
  });
  swapTurns();
}
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach. You will likely need a fair few polyfills for IE11

Comment: Look in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8