# Illegal invocation with document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Related jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cWCZs/1/

The following code works perfectly:

```
var qs = function( s ) {
    return document.querySelector( s );
};
qs( 'some selector' );
```

But the following doesn't:

```
var qs = document.querySelector;
qs( 'some selector' ); // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

I don't understand why.

My confusion comes with the fact that this works:

```
function t() {
    console.log( 'hi' );
}
var s = t;
s(); // "hi"
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem lies in the `this` value.

```
//in the following simile, obj is the document, and test is querySelector
var obj = {
    test : function () {
        console.log( this );
    }
};

obj.test(); //logs obj

var t = obj.test;
t(); //logs the global object
```

`querySelector` is not a generic method, it will not accept another `this` value. So, if you want a shortcut, you must make sure your `querySelector` is bound to the document:

```
var qs = document.querySelector.bind( document );
```

Comment: Oh, that's a way better solution than the duplicate.