# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" when using "document.querySelector"

Tags: javascript

I have this simple two-liner bit of JS that keeps erroring with 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation".

```js
const $ = document.querySelector;
$('#someElementId').display = 'none';
```

```html
<p id="someElementId">The element</p>
```

Comment: You lose the `document` context when you detach the method. You'd need something like `const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `style` property.

Use the following code:

`$('#someElementId').style.display='none`';

And to fix the `Illegal Invocation`, as stated in the comment by [@phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) and as posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637169/16408272), you have to make sure to bound your `querySelector` to the document:

```
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
```

Here a finally working snippet:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind( document );
$('#someElementId').style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<p id="someElementId">The element</p>
```

Comment: OP would need this but it doesn't solve the _"illegal invocation"_ error

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I missed that as well, thanks.

Side note: I'm fairly new to posting, how do I mark a comment as the solution?

Comment: @R0bl0x10501050 you don't

Comment: @Phil is right about the bind. I'm updating the answer to reflect the suggestion!