# Using document.getElementById as a first-class function

Tags: javascript, dom, functional-programming

As a functional programming language, JavaScript allows statements like

```
var obj = {
    key: function () {return true;}
};
var fn = obj.key;
```

Simple enough, but why does this not work?

```
$ = document.getElementById;
```

The assignment itself does not throw any errors, but attempting to use the `$` function throws `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` in Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` is a method that needs a context (`this`) set to `document` to work as expected.

One way is to call it using

```
fn = document.getElementById;

fn.call(document, 'some-id');
```

or you can use ES5 fumction `bind` (which will fix the context) like this:

```
fn = document.getElementById.bind(document);

fn('some-id');
```

or you can do what `bind` does in the end by yourself:

```
fn = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

fn('some-id');
```

JavaScript is quite different in its handling of methods as regular functions and supplying the calling context for a method very dynamically. You can even override `this` by using `call` or `apply` methods of the functions themselves (even function is an object that has methods, these inherited from Function.prototype).

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare it as a `function` and specify the parameter(s) you’ll need:

```
var $ = function(id){
return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution, I'm asking about the language specifications that prohibit the assigning the getElementById function to a variable