# Replace functions in javascript (to shorten phonegap plugins commands)

Tags: javascript, cordova

I need to shorten my functions (I use them a lot, if i shorten them probably my app needs less storage)

For Example I have `navigator.notification.confirm`

it is a function. I call it like this : `navigator.notification.confirm(a, b, c, [d, e, f, ...])`

I want to shorten it as : `confirm(a, b, c, [d, e, f, ...])`

I used `var confirm = navigator.notification.confirm` but it doesn't work :(

I can use `function confirm(a, b, c, d) { navigator.notification.confirm(a, b, c, d) }`

but isn't there any shorter way ?

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1007340/2088135

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I do this for navigator.notification.alert:

I put this in my function that is called from the deviceReady event.

```
    //Shortcut for navigator.notification.alert
    if (navigator.notification) {
        window.alert = function (message,func,title,buttonTxt) {
            if(!func){
                func = null;
            }
            navigator.notification.alert(message, func, title, buttonTxt);
        };
    }
```

Now with this code in place, anytime I want to alert something I can do this:

```
alert('hi');
```

instead of:

```
navigator.notification.alert('hi');
```

Comment: That is short sighted. You write this function once, then anytime you want to call it you use `alert(message);`. That is shorter in the long run.