# Why element.matches' polyfill doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to polyfill the `Element.matches` a method for IE.
I found these code on MDN:

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
Element.prototype.matches = 
    Element.prototype.matchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || 
    this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i = matches.length;
        while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
        return i > -1;            
    };
}
```

So I write some codes like:

```
function matches(node, selector) {
if (node.matches) {
    return node.matches(selector)
}

const match = node.matchesSelector || 
                            node.webkitMatchesSelector || 
                            node.mozMatchesSelector || 
                            node.msMatchesSelector || 
                            node.oMatchesSelector || 
                            function (s) {
           const matches = (node.ownerDocument || document).querySelectorAll(s) 
                                let i = matches.length
                                while (--i >= 0 && matches[i] !== node) {}
                                return i > -1
                           }
     return match(selector)
   }
```

Though, I know this will work on most browsers except IE
I deleted most of the code, and tested it for IE,  this worked:

```
function match(node, selector) {
        return node.msMatchesSelector(selector)
}
```

I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
function match(node, selector) {
      var isMatch = node.msMatchesSelector
      return isMatch(selector)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function aliasing doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: You use `querySelector()` in your polyfill instead of `querySelectorAll()` so the returned value will not have a `.length` and thus the loop can never be entered.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I found and collected it but it still didn't work.

Comment: Thanks Andreas.You pointed out the core problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that

```
return node.msMatchesSelector(selector)
```

works and

```
var isMatch = node.msMatchesSelector
return isMatch(selector)
```

does not is because in the second case, the context of `isMatch` (the `this`) is `undefined` instead of `node`. You could write it like this, assuming IE supports `bind()`:

```
var isMatch = node.msMatchesSelector.bind(node)
return isMatch(selector)
```

or simply just wrap the function to ensure you do not need support for `bind()`:

```
var isMatch = function (s) { return node.msMatchesSelector(s) }
return isMatch(selector)
```

but that seems quite frivolous since you're only using the function once, so you might as well use the initial method in one line.

Comment: Yeah, that is it.Thanks for your awesome answer.It seems that IE doesn't support `bind()`.