# why does this specific case of exitFullscreen not work?

Tags: javascript

I have the following request_fullscreen which works:

```js
    const request_fullscreen = function() {

        const elm = document.documentElement;

        const method = elm.requestFullScreen || 
                            elm.webkitRequestFullScreen || 
                            elm.mozRequestFullScreen || 
                            elm.msRequestFullScreen;

        method.call(elm);
    }
```

This does not work:

```js
    const exit_fullscreen = function() {

        const method = document.exitFullscreen ||
                       document.webkitCancelFullScreen ||
                       document.mozCancelFullScreen ||
                       document.msExitFullscreen;

        method.call();
    }
```

While this works:

```js
    const exit_fullscreen = function() {

        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
             document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
```

Why does the one where I or them together not work?

Comment: Did you try `method.call(document);` ?

Comment: In order to understand why the first exit_fullscreen doe not work, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007340/javascript-function-aliasing-doesnt-seem-to-work